# Foreach throws error with %dopar% but executes successfully with %do%

Tags: r, parallel-processing

I am trying to convert the following code into parallel using `foreach` and `%dopar%`.

```
library(doSNOW)
library(foreach)
cl<- makeCluster(4, type = "SOCK")
registerDoSNOW(cl)

min_subid <- c()
max_subid <- c()
p_typ <- c()
p_nm <- c()
st_tm<-c()
end_tm <- c()
supp <- c()
chart_type <- c()

foreach(j =1:noOfPhases)    %dopar%
{
  start_time    <-phases[j, colnames(phases)=="StartTime"]
  end_time      <-phases[j, colnames(phases)=="StopTime"]
  phase_type    <-phases[j, colnames(phases)=="Phase_Type_Id"]
  phase_name    <-phases[j, colnames(phases)=="Phase_Name"]
  suppress      <-phases[j, colnames(phases)=="Suppression_Time"]
  chart_typ     <-phases[j, colnames(phases)=="chartType"]

  conft<-(masterData$Time.Subgroup>=start_time & masterData$Time.Subgroup<=end_time)

  masterData[which(conft), colnames(masterData)=="Phase_Type"]<-phase_type
  masterData[which(conft), colnames(masterData)=="Phase_Name"]<-phase_name

  min_subid <- rbind(min_subid, min(which(conft)))
  max_subid <- rbind(max_subid, max(which(conft)))
  p_typ     <- rbind( p_typ, masterData$Phase_Type[min(which(conft))])
  p_nm      <- rbind( p_nm, masterData$Phase_Name[min(which(conft))])
  st_tm     <- rbind( st_tm, as.character(start_time))
  end_tm    <- rbind( end_tm, as.character(end_time))
  supp      <- rbind(supp,as.character(suppress))
  chart_type <- rbind(chart_type,as.character(chart_typ))

  phase_info <- data.frame(Subgrp_No_Start=min_subid, Subgrp_No_End=max_subid, Phase_Type=p_typ, 
                           Phase_Name=p_nm, Start_Time=st_tm, Stop_Time=end_tm,
                                             Suppression_Time=supp,ChartType=chart_type) 
}

 phase_output<-merge(phase_info, phases, by.x=c("Start_Time",
   "Stop_Time","ChartType"), by.y=c("StartTime", "StopTime","chartType"))
```

---

The above code executes successfully when `%do%` is included instead of `%dopar%`. can anyone help me in understanding why I get the following error when it runs parallel (`%dopar%`) and runs successfully on sequential (`%do%`)

```
Error in merge(phase_info, phases, by.x = c("Start_Time", "Stop_Time",  : 
  object 'phase_info' not found
```

Comment: Show us the error that you get for `%dopar%`. I'm guessing that the current error just tells us that your foreach didn't produce the correct result (or none at all).

Answer (score 5):

The solution is really simple, but I start off with an explanation of what is happening when you execute the code to explain the error.

What happens in your `foreach` block is that the one data frame (`phase_info`) is created for each value of `j` and they are returned together in a list. However, since your assignment `phase_info <- data.frame(...)` is located inside the `foreach` rather than outside, the list is not stored anywhere and gets discarded. The cause for confusion is that when using `%do%` you create all the data frames sequentially on the *master node* and when using `%dopar%` the frames are being created in parallel on the *worker nodes*. The following `merge` command is executed on the master node causing an error if you used `%dopar%` since `phase_info` does not exist in its workspace. Also note that when using `%do%` like above, each iterations of `foreach` overwrites the result of the previous ones (*i.e.* you get only the result of the last iteration).

This minor change fixes it:

```
phase_info <- foreach(...) %dopar% {
    ...

    data.frame(Subgrp_No_Start=min_subid, Subgrp_No_End=max_subid, Phase_Type=p_typ, 
                           Phase_Name=p_nm, Start_Time=st_tm, Stop_Time=end_tm,
                                             Suppression_Time=supp,ChartType=chart_type)
    # No need to give it a name as it will be returned and the name forgotten
}
phase_output <- merge(phase_info, ...)
```

As I mentioned above, `phase_info` will now be a list where each element is a data frame. I am just guessing now but you probably want to execute the `merge` elementwise then, like this:

```
phase_output <- lapply(phase_info, merge, phases, by.x=c("Start_Time",
     "Stop_Time","ChartType"), by.y=c("StartTime", "StopTime","chartType"))
```