# Parallel packages doSNOW and foreach not working

Tags: r, parallel-processing

I have put some sample code to make you understand my problem.

```
library(doSNOW)
library(foreach)
cl<-makeCluster(2,type='SOCK')
registerDoSNOW(cl)
foreach(i = 1:files, .combine=rbind) %dopar% 
{   
   for(j in 1:nrow(df[[i]]))       
   {    
        key = as.vector(df[[i]][j,1])
        df[p,2]=key
   }
}
```

when i try to use parallel packages `doSNOW` and `foreach`, it gives me some error:

`task 2 failed - "undefined columns selected"`.

As i tried to understand the error, put could not make it out. Can any one help please

Edited: 
Data frame `df` contains 300 files of 50000 rows each and data frame `df1` contains 1 files of 60000 rows, and i want to summarize the 300 files in one data frame say `d1` by using my master file `df1`
My sample code is given below

```
df = list.files(pattern=".csv")
df = lapply(daf, function(x) read.csv(x, header = FALSE))
files = length(df)
df1 = read.csv(file.choose())
row1 = nrow(df1)
p = 1
foreach(i = 1:files, .combine=rbind)%dopar%       
{   
    for(j in 1:nrow(df[[i]]))
    {   
        key = as.vector(df[[i]][j,1])
        k = BinSearch(df1[,1], key,row1)    
        if (k != 0)
        {
             d1[p,1] = df1[k,10]
         p+1
    }
 print(d1)
```

As it takes more time so i wanted to use `doSNOW` and `foreach` packages but gets the above mentioned error.

Comment: No clue what is going on. 1. What are the variables `files` & `df`? 2. If `df` is a list of `data.frame`s as it seems like, what would you expect         `df[p,2]` to retreive? 3. What is `p`? Please consider adding more information to your question.

Comment: @fgnu ...thanks for your comment. Editing is done

Comment: There is an error in your code (what is `d1`?). Where is the `BinSearch` function defined? This is probably far more easily achieved using `parLapply`.

Comment: @fgnu... `d1` and `BinSearch` are defined , but i didn't put that in the above code. The code is working fine. But when i want to use parallel processing, it gives the error.

Comment: Try walking thru your code (via `debug` perhaps) to verify that things like `rbind` are in fact producing matrices with at least `j` rows .

Comment: @CarlWitthoft ... when i use %do% it returns the values, but with %dopar% it returns NULL May i know why NULL

Comment: POssible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12650457/foreach-throws-error-with-dopar-but-executes-successfully-with-do?rq=1